# "message.member.voice" returning undefined even when I'm in a voice channel - discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord bot play music for my discord server (in light of groovy shutting down).

But when I tried to get it to join using `message.members.voice.join()` it always returns undefined, even when I'm in a discord voice channel. I've left and rejoined the call, and restarted the bot, but nothing has worked.

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const { voiceChannel } = message.member.voice;


    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Join a Voice-Channel to use this command');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();


    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);



      return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

    }


    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' })
      connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 });


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using v13?

Comment: What is your discord.js version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@discordjs/voice` package for discord.js v13.

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice')
```

And join voice or stage channels with the `joinVoiceChannel` method

```js
let connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    ...
})
```

You need to specify the options as shown in [their documentation](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#joinvoicechannel)

Though I'm not sure about playing audio, there is a method `joinVoiceChannel.subscribe()` that takes `AudioPlayer` as parameter, which allows the player to play audio on the connection.

You could make an `AudioPlayer` by using `createAudioPlayer()`. But there is a method `play` in `AudioPlayer`, that takes `AudioResource` as parameter, which plays the resource in the player.

And to make AudioResource, use `createAudioResource` method, which takes `input` as parameter.

```js
const {joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource} = require('@discordjs/voice')
let player = createAudioPlayer()
connection.subscribe(player)

let resource = createAudioResource('')
player.play(resource)
```

Though I'm still not sure about the value for the parameter, it could be URL or file paths, I haven't tested it out since I'm currently out

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js version 12 you would need to get the `GuildMember#voice` state's `VoiceChannel` object they are connected to so you would have to use [`VoiceState#channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel) so you would to define your connection like so:

```js
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join()
```